# Как можно повесить событие скролла на блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Блок вначале страницы имеет определённую высоту в пикселях и `overflow:auto;`
Нужно, что бы при скроле, при нахождении курсора в любом месте, скролился сначала этот блок, а потом вся страница.

Знаю, что нужно  отловить событие

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
//код
}
```

Как можно сделать ума не приложу.

Comment: Извините, добавил тег jquery
Да курсор может находиться в любом месте, главное что бы сначала скролился блок.

Answer (score 1):

```
  block.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if(e.detail=='down') block.scrollTop+=5;
    });
    window.onscroll = function(evt) {
        if(block.scrollTop < 190) {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            let event = new Event("scroll");
            event.detail= 'down';
            block.dispatchEvent(event);
        }   
    }
```